# Problem whit add sequence in Oracle and Spring

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate

I get this error when  I try add new record

```
Hibernate:
    select
        STEST_PP_DATA_SEQ.nextval
    from
        dual
2022-04-06 12:53:03.487  WARN 23884 --- [0.1-8082-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 2289, SQLState: 42000
2022-04-06 12:53:03.510 ERROR 23884 --- [0.1-8082-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
```

My Class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "TEST_PP_DATA")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "STEST_PP_DATA_SEQ", sequenceName = "STEST_PP_DATA_SEQ", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
public class TestPPData extends AuditableEntity{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "STEST_PP_DATA_SEQ")
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
```

This how I add sequence to my DB

```
CREATE SEQUENCE STEST_PP_DATA_SEQ INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOMAXVALUE MINVALUE 1 NOCYCLE NOCACHE NOORDER
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need to fully qualify the name. Can you try the following query to retrieve the owner:

```
SELECT owner, status
  FROM All_Objects
 WHERE object_type = 'SEQUENCE'
   AND object_name = 'STEST_PP_DATA_SEQ';
```

and then use the sequence as:

```
select <OWNER>.STEST_PP_DATA_SEQ.nextval
  from dual;
```

and if the first query doesn't return anything or the status is different from VALID, then you have a problem in your sequence creation.

Comment: This query correctly returns the owner and the status = Valid. I can up (nextval) the number but only from the database client.

Comment: Can you try to following: CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM STEST_PP_SEQ for OWNER.STEST_PP_DATA_SEQ and then
SELECT STEST_PP_SEQ.nexval FROM DUAL in your code.

Comment: I already know why it doesn't work. You were right. I am new to the project and it turns out that this one of user does not have full access to one of the databases